# C# => on argument

Tags: c#

So, I have this in my code:

```
excluirCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Deletar(), param => this.PodeDeletar());
```

RelayCommand constructor receives an `Action<object>` type, and a `Predicate<object>` type as parameters.

My question is, without the `param =>`, `this.Deletar()` cannot be used as a parameter for the constructor (`this.Deletar()` is a void type method), so exactly what does `param =>` do?

Comment: You are asking why `this.Deletar()`, which is a void method, is not an `Action<object>`?

Comment: Exactly, i mean why the Action<object> is accepting a void method? As far as i know if an argument is of determined type you need to give it the same type on the method invocation.

Comment: Because you are creating the action on the method call. If this wasn't understood in the current answer, let me know and I'll explain further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The param is an input parameter to the action delegate. Your action may or may not need it.

The `param => this.Deletar()` is logically equivalent to a method like this:

```
public void MyDelegate(object param)
{
    this.Deletar();
}
```

In order for your Deletar method to conform to the required signature for the RelayCommand method it would need to return void and take a single object parameter, like `MyDelegate` above.

Comment: So this works because Action type is a delegate? I don't know much about delegates maybe that is the problem. I mean could this type of syntax works if "Action" was just some random class i created?